# Angular dynamically check and update validators

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive

I need to dynamically add a validator to an angular form control from a directive.

Simplified:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'my-directive' })
export class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit  {
  @Input() myDirective: boolean;
  control: AbstractControl;
  constructor(private form: NgForm, private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const name = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('name');
      this.control = this.form.controls[name];
      // this.control.setValidator... kills my other validators.
    });
  }
}
```

How do I check if this control has a "required" attribute, and set it if not? Without overriding other validators?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!this.control.hasError('required') {
   let existingErrors = this.control.errors;
   existingErrors['required'] = {'required': ''};
   this.control.setErrors(existingErrors);
}
```

First check whether control already has a required error and if it doesn't - add it to the existing errors and set updated errors back to the control

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, please do not post code-only answers, instead attempt to explain your approach to the problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.